# Save response to "variable" angular

Tags: angular, response

How can I save this response to a variable so that I can access it from other functions?

Code:

```
        export interface launchResponse {
    
        status: number;
        url: string;
        token: string;
      }
    
        export interface launchResponseObject {
        response: launchResponse;
      }
```

Then in a service:

```
          LAUNCHRESPONSE: launchResponseObject[] = [];
    
      async getData() {
    
        try {
          const LAUNCHRESPONSE = await this.http
            .get<launchResponseObject>(
              `${$apiUrl}`
            )
            .toPromise();
    
            console.log(LAUNCHRESPONSE.response.url)
            console.log(LAUNCHRESPONSE.response.token)

    
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(`Promise rejected with ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        }
      }
```

I know I can save it like this: this.url = LAUNCHRESPONSE.response.url but I want to save the whole thing and then access it like I do in this function in other functions aswell.

I've also tried using this.LAUNCHRESPONSE instead of the const LAUNCHRESPONSE with no luck..I know it's something really stupid but I can't find out what.

Comment: Show us what you tried that didn't work

Comment: For example instead of const LAUNCHRESPONSE I tried to use this.LAUNCHRESPONSE and I get: Type 'launchResponseObject' is missing the following properties from type 'launchResponseObject[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: You declared the variable as an array but declared the API call to return a single item. You have to choose which one is correct and fix the other.

Comment: The API definitely doesn’t return an array but an object with more objects inside. If I can access the first object that’s enough for now. How can I fix the declaration? I tried LAUNCHRESPONSE = {} bit still couldn’t get it to work..while I have an api that returns an array of objects and I did that without any problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by saving the whole thing and access like the function you have written. If your requirement is to get the value you got from api response without calling it again, you can use a getter function for it after setting the api response using **this.LAUNCHRESPONSE** .

Your service will look like this :

```
  LAUNCHRESPONSE: launchResponseObject[] = [];

  async getData() {

    try {
      this.LAUNCHRESPONSE = await this.http
        .get<launchResponseObject>(
          `${$apiUrl}`
        )
        .toPromise();

        console.log(LAUNCHRESPONSE.response.url)
        console.log(LAUNCHRESPONSE.response.token)


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Promise rejected with ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    }
  }

getStoredResponseData(){
  return this.LAUNCHRESPONSE;
}
```

You can call the **getStoredResponseData()** declared inside the service to get the response details later on.

Comment: This doesn't work as when I try to do it I get:
Type 'launchResponseObject' is missing the following properties from type 'launchResponseObject[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: Are you sure that what you get back from the API is an array of launchResponseObjects..? The issue you have now is that you’re typing is inconsistent. Either change .get<launchResponseObject> to .get<launchResponseObject[]>  or change LAUNCHRESPONSE: launchResponseObject[] = [] to  LAUNCHRESPONSE: launchResponseObject = {}

Comment: What I get in the response isn’t an array but an object, yes. I’ll try when I get back but I think I already tried that. Will report back.

Comment: This actually works but I had to modify the code a bit, including the interface. Thanks!

Comment: So the main issue you were facing was due to data type.